# How to find the coordinates of the vertices of a pentagon centered at the origin

Tags: geometry

I am attempting to follow this tutorial here: http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonradius.html

My goal is to find the coordinates of vertices of a pentagon, given some radius. For example, if I know that the center is at $(0,0)$, and my radius is $8.1$, what formula can I use to get the coordinates of points A, E, B, D, C, if I know the center point between D, C (i.e $(0,5)$
[image]

Comment: You need a supplementary assumption : visibly this assumption is that segment dc is horizontal, i.e., ordinate of $c$ = ordinate of $d$.

Comment: @JeanMarie can you show an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us start from vertex $b=(0 ; 8.1)$.

Turning **clockwise** by $72°$ (recall: $72°=360°/5$), one meets vertex $a$. It means that if one materiallizes the $x$ axis, the angle between $Oa$ and the horizontal axis is $90°-72°=18°$. Thus the coordinates of $a$ are $(8.1 \cos(18°) ; 8.1 \sin(18°))$.

Doing once again the same thing (turning clockwise by $72°$), one meets vertex $C$, with angle cOa $= 72°$, thus line segment makes an angle $72°-18°=54°$ below the horizontal axis, thus considered as $-54°$.

Therefore, the coordinates of $c$ are $(8.1 \cos(-54°) ; 8.1 \sin(-54°))$.

The coordinates of $e$ and $d$ are easily deduced from the coordinates of $a$ and $c$ by symmetry.

Comment: the value of X for coordinate c would equate to -6.717.. but it is on the right side of the x axis. why is that negative?

Comment: No. $8.1*cos(-54°)=8.1*cos(+54°)=4.761$

Comment: Are you sure you have worked in degrees ? And not in radians ?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming starting with   b on $y$ axis,

$$(x,y)=  ( 8.1 \cos ( t + k \, 2 \pi/5)  , 8.1 \sin( t + k\, 2 \pi/5)) $$

where $t$ is polar coordinate angle at (0,0)  and $k$ is varied between 0 to 5 to arrive at all vertex coordinates of the regular pentagon.

Comment: This is the proper way to answer the question.  Then the points can be rotated accordingly by adding on components from desired angle adjustments.  But I suspect the OP is not familiar with basic complex fifth roots of unity.

Comment: what do the t and the k stand for? can the same formula be applied to other points of interest?

Comment: $t$ is polar angle  $ =\tan^{-1} (y/x)$ and $k$ is used to jump from one triangle of pentagon to the other. These arise when considering $\frac15$ th root of unity in complex plane... a method more suitable to calculate regular polygons.

Answer (score 2):

To find the coordinates of the vertices of a pentagon centered at the origin:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Narasimham's answer, the geometry of complex numbers can be used to solve this problem.

In the complex plane, multiplying two numbers on the unit circle results in another number on the unit circle, where the argument of the product is the sum of the arguments of the factors (the argument of a complex number is its angle with the positive $x$-axis, measured counter-clockwise from the positive $x$-axis). In other words, multiplying a given complex number on the unit circle by another results in rotating the first one counter-clockwise by the second one. In the image below, multiplying $w_2$ by $w_1$ results in rotating $w_2$ by $w_1$ to reach $w_1 \cdot w_2$.

[image: Multiplying complex numbers on the unit circle]

Start with $w_1 = \cos{(2\pi/5)} + i \sin{(2\pi/5)}$ and take its powers in order to array five equally spaced points around the circle:

\begin{align}
w_1 &= \cos{(2\pi/5)} + i \sin{(2\pi/5)}\\
w_2 &= w_1^2 = \cos{(4\pi/5)} + i \sin{(4\pi/5)}\\
w_3 &= w_1^3 = \cos{(6\pi/5)} + i \sin{(6\pi/5)}\\
w_4 &= w_1^4 = \cos{(8\pi/5)} + i \sin{(8\pi/5)}\\
w_5 &= w_1^5 = \cos{(10\pi/5)} + i \sin{(10\pi/5)} = 1
\end{align}

[image: Pentagon points around the unit circle]

The problem now is that the pentagon produced is not in the same orientation as that desired by the OP. Easily fixed! The complex number $i$ has argument $\pi/2$, so multiplying by $i$ has the effect of rotating a point on the unit circle counter-clockwise by $\pi/2$:

[image: Pentagon points around the unit circle]

These points can now be scaled (multiplied by 8.1) to find the pentagon points around a circle of radius 8.1.

Computer graphics applications may require pentagon points not centered around the origin. In that case, translate the points calculated previously (add some increment $h_0$ to every $x$ coordinate and another increment $k_0$ to every $y$ coordinate).

In summary: Find the pentagon points around the unit circle, then rotate, scale, and translate to find any regular pentagon in the plane.